# what's the proper way to handle timeouts for active record with a connection pool?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, multithreading, activerecord, exception

I've tracked down a strange error `` undefined method `run_callbacks' for nil:NilClass `` and been able to reproduce it with this sample code.

Basically the problem is active record is getting a timeout (the default is 5s) but throwing an undefined method exception, which seems wrong to me.

But anyway, what's the right way to handle this?  In my real code, I have a bunch of threads that are busy doing real work but occasionally I hit this error.  So imagine the `puts` is the real code.  I want the existing threads to keep working away when this happens.

```
threads = []
10.times do |n|

 threads <<  Thread.new {
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |conn|
      puts "#{n} #{conn}"
      res =  conn.execute("select sleep(6)", :async => true)
    end
  }
end

# block and wait for all threads to finish
threads.each { |t| puts "joined" ; t.join }
rescue Exception => e
  puts  $!, $@
end
```

If I run this code as is I get the exception.  If I reduce the sleep to 4s I don't.  Here's the output with the 6s sleep.

```
joined
0 #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0xb73c6380>
1 #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0xb73c5548>
2 #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0xb73c4fe4>
3 #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0xb73c4a80>
4 #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter:0xb73c451c>
joined
joined
joined
joined
joined
undefined method `run_callbacks' for nil:NilClass
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.2.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:212:in `checkin'
sqltst.rb:31:in `join'
sqltst.rb:31
sqltst.rb:31:in `each'
sqltst.rb:31
```

Comment: Do you get the same error, if you try to catch the exception inside the thread?

Comment: How to handle it depends a bit upon the nature of your queries. I assume that since they are run in seperate threads, the queries in each thread are contextually isolated from each other. In this case I would definitely handle the error within the thread itself. Do 3 retries on timeouts and then set a "thread-return-code" and exit the thread. If you are doing updates, then of course pack them into a transaction - ActiveRecord supports this.

Comment: If you just want to code to keep running have you tried adding 'rescue nil' to the end of your block?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of work was done in this area for ActiveRecord since this question was posted. Here are some good explanations: http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2012/03/15/activerecord-concurrency-currently-good-news-and-bad/

Answer (score 0):

You should set pool: 10 in your database.yml. Seems like you have reached the limit.